# How to solve Xcode compile warning: "when processing... in... no such file or directory"?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

When I build in `Debug` schema, I see no warnings, but in `Release` I get 2 warnings:

```
while processing /Users/[path to my xcode project]/libUserVoice.a(UserVoice.o):
warning: /var/folders/s_/m1fjy19n3_x5tnr4pfvx_z1c1111gp/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.0-7A218/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/UserVoice_Prefix-cemskxhozggatlabrcxqvydduxjw/UserVoice_Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/[path to my xcode project]/libUserVoice.a(UserVoice.o):
warning: /var/folders/s_/m1fjy19n3_x5tnr4pfvx_z1c1111gp/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.0-7A218/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/UserVoice_Prefix-axbllcwdvmtdfsgaozoqlvgidayx/UserVoice_Prefix.pch.pch: No such file or directory
```

In fact there is no such directory as `/var/folder/s_`.
I think I this is the first release build since update to Xcode 7.3.

What did **not** help so far:

- Cleaning build folder
- Restarting Xcode
- Removing files in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- Removing files in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/
- Removing folders and files in all folders `/var/folders/.../SharedPrecompiledHeaders`

What I observed:

- The Xcode parameter `Precompiled Headers Cache Path` points to a different directory `/var/folders/ck/...`

What is the reason for these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

OK what finally helped was:

- Removing the library `libUserVoice.a` mentioned in the warning
- Getting the source code from github and rebuilding the library
- Adding the newly built library

When I removed the new library and replaced it with the old one the warnings appeared again. The old one is a compiled binary that is provided by the vendor. So it seems this has nothing to do with Xcode but with the vendor's build. Still, if anyone can shed light on this issue it would be interesting to know the background.

**Hint:** Make sure to build the library as a universal binary so it can run on both ARM (iOS device) and i386 (iOS Simulator) architectures.